# Under what conditions might a police station enlist the help of a minor?

Tags: government, law, law-enforcement

The story is set in New York City, and the protagonist is a world-renowned for solving mysteries. However, they are only fourteen years old. Would it be illegal for her to assist the police in solving a murder? What kind of red tape would the department need to navigate in order to enlist her help?

Comment: This would depend on how the rules of your world/society work and you've not offered us that context. Please review the site's rules about how to ask an [on-topic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) question.

Comment: This may be better suited for our sister site: https://law.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Well she's a prodigy. That means the world will naturally treat her differently. See this example of a 7 year old being allowed to do surgical procedures:

https://yourstory.com/2016/03/akrit-jaswal

This but one of many peculiar examples of prodigies who, due to their brains clearly maturing faster than their bodies, will at times be treated like actual, respectable adults. If your character is already worldly renowned as a detective prodigy, she has already undergone the part of proving she's got what it takes. Therefore it'd likely be just another day for her, though it's likely she'll still have someone (caretaker/sidekick?) who would likely tend to her physical needs, as her body is still maturing. You could however detail more of her backstory, describing bits of her life and how she came to be renowned worldwide both as exposition of her capabilities and as well a means of establishing her main traits in your story.

If anything, we might have an issue with certain groups arguing whether they should treat her by her mental of physical age. As, while she already behaves like an adult, her body and most importantly brain are still maturing, which could raise concerns over how this much exposure of herself to violence could be detrimental for her mental health,as this is also widely discussed in our societies as a real problem. See the following:https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3869039/ to have a better picture of the possible obstacles your character might have to overcome.

Comment: Needs must. If the Major is willing to press for results when his wife was kidnapped, the Police Commissioner isn't going to turn away a potential lead.